# Assigning name to usb device

Tags: usb

I have more than one (two in this case) device that uses the same serial chip, a ch340

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b404 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 055: ID 1d57:fa20 Xenta 
**Bus 003 Device 060: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter**
**Bus 003 Device 059: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter**
Bus 003 Device 058: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

i would like to assing a different name to these device. how should i do it? 
i thought to write a rule in udev/rules.d but i am not sure since the id and pid is the same

as suggested by @jean-marie this is the output of

udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ch341-uart"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1.1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ch341"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1':
    KERNELS=="3-1.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="96mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0254"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="4"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0-Serial"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="22"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0402"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0610"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="GenesysLogic"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="44"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0408"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.8.0-46-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="42"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="24"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x201f"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

and for usb1

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/ttyUSB1':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="ch341-uart"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ch341"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3':
    KERNELS=="3-1.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="96mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0254"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.3"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="7523"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0-Serial"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="20"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0402"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0610"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="GenesysLogic"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="59"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0408"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.8.0-46-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="42"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="24"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x201f"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: Try to find a serial number in the output of this command 'udevadm info  --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk'  then you could make a rule based on the serial number.

Comment: @Jean-Marie I added the output in the main question, do you have any idea how to make this rule?

Comment: I cannot see a serial number in the output., so cannot use that route. I will try to figure a way using the physical port used. I have to go for now. Will come back tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks you are very friendly :) anyway do you know how could i clean the list of usb decices? I have made a lot of plug/unplug and i am arrived to use the device 100 on the third usb port opsss :( i mean it is not necessary but i don t like to see all these "fake" devices

Comment: Sorry for the delay,  see my answer below for naming your usb devices. I do not know how to reset devices numbers, but it will reset when you reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your devices do not supply a serial number, udev cannot differentiate between them. It can however assign a different name based on which USB port is used.

Make some udev rules that can uniquely identify your devices and the port where it is connected and assign a name based on where it is plugged.

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/serial-ports.rules
```

Paste these two lines:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNELS=="3-1.1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="device1"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNELS=="3-1.3", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="device2"
```

Save and restart udev.

Now when you plug one adapter un USB port 1 it will be named "device1" and the one in port 3 will be named "device2". You can use the names you wish or add more rules for other USB ports

Comment: follow-up: after a few months of not connecting the two devices for some reason them changed the KERNEL parameter so they are back not distinguishable. So this method (at least with my ubuntu and CH340) is not permanent